# Swift 2 dimensional dictionary of any objects

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to do the following in swift, but obviously I'm missing something syntactically:

```
var mediaCardSet: [Int: [String: Any]]()
```

A sample would be:

```
[1: [
    "key1" : UILabel,
    "key2" : UIView
]]
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's nothing wrong in the type - you are just using the wrong syntax for initializing it:

```
var mediaCardSet = [Int: [String: Any]]()
                 ^
```

If instead you don't want to initialize, just declare the variable/property, you don't need the parenthesis at the end:

```
var mediaCardSet: [Int: [String: Any]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Umm.. an equal to?

```
var mediaCardSet = [Int: [String: Any]]()
```

Answer (score 1):

This declares `mediaCardSet`, creates an empty dictionary of the type you want, and assigns the empty dictionary to `mediaCardSet`:

```
var mediaCardSet = [Int: [String: Any]]()
```

The compiler deduces the type of `mediaCardSet`.

This assigns a literal value to `mediaCardSet`:

```
mediaCardSet = [1: [
    "key1" : UILabel.self,
    "key2" : UIView.self
]]
```

(Note that your original code missed a closing bracket, and tried to use class names as literals.)

Since `mediaCardSet` is a `var`, you can also modify it like this:

```
mediaCardSet[1] = [
    "key1" : UILabel.self,
    "key2" : UIView.self
]
```